# Error object of type 'NoneType' has no len() with json and csv

Tags: python, latitude-longitude

I'm new to the python language (python3.6). I try to have iris with longitude and latitude, but I have some errors that I can't correct.

What i want to achieve : I have coordinates (latitude and longitude) in a CSV file. In the other hand i have a `geojson`file where i have polygons shapes. I would like to see if my coordinates are contained in the range of each polygon of my file.

But i have some trouble with the code below, i don't understand the following error `Error object of type 'NoneType' has no len() at the last block of code`.

If my post miss some details please tell me, i'll be glad to add some informations to help you understand the situation :)

This is my code :

```
import json, csv
import numpy
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point

def readJson(url):
    response = open(url)
    return json.loads(response.read())

def readCSV(url):
    response = open(url)
    return csv.DictReader(response, delimiter=',')

def getIris():
    """
    Returns a dictionary formed by the id of an iris and its coordinates.
    """
    dict = {}
    url = 'iris.json'
    data2 = readJson(url)
    for district in data2['features']:
        dict[district['id']] = district['geometry']

    return dict
def getPOIs():
    """
    Returns a list of tuples of POIs lat/long coordinates.
    """
    urls = [
        "./result.csv",
         ]

    POIs = []

    for url in urls:
        csv = readCSV(url)
        for line in csv:
            latitude = line.get('latitude', None)
            longitude = line.get('longitude', None)
            if latitude is not None and longitude is not None:
                POIs.append((float(longitude), float(latitude)))
    return POIs

def POIsInIris(iris, POIs):
    """
    Returns a dictionary formed by the id of a iris and the number of POIs that falls in
    this iris.
    """
    dict = {}

    for key, value in iris.items():
        dict[key] = 0
        polygon = shape(value)
        for p in POIs:
            point = Point(p[0], p[1])
            # print point.wkt
            if polygon.contains(point):
                dict[key] += 1

    return dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Geographical Features
    iris_bbox = getIris()
    iris_number = len(iris_bbox)
    print ("Iris: ", iris_number)

    print ("Reading POIs...")
    POIs = getPOIs()
    print (len(POIs))
    print ("Done Reading POIs")
    print ("Calculating POIs per Iris")
    POIsPerIris = POIsInIris(iris_bbox, POIs)
    for k,v in POIsPerIris.items():
        print (k,v)
```

And the output :

```
Iris:  49404
Reading POIs...
0
Done Reading POIs
Calculating POIs per Iris
```

Moreover I have a 0 for print (len(POIs)), and I don't understand why.

Thank you a lot

Edit : Here is the full error message :

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-247f0f9756f9> in <module>()
     10     print ("Done Reading POIs")
     11     print ("Calculating POIs per Iris")
---> 12     POIsPerIris = POIsInIris(iris_bbox, POIs)
     13     for k,v in POIsPerIris.items():
     14         print (k,v)

<ipython-input-54-0877c0182800> in POIsInIris(iris, POIs)
      8     for key, value in iris.items():
      9         dict[key] = 0
---> 10         polygon = shape(value)
     11         for p in POIs:
     12             point = Point(p[0], p[1])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/shapely/geometry/geo.py in shape(context)
     39         return MultiLineString(ob["coordinates"])
     40     elif geom_type == "multipolygon":
---> 41         return MultiPolygon(ob["coordinates"], context_type='geojson')
     42     elif geom_type == "geometrycollection":
     43         geoms = [shape(g) for g in ob.get("geometries", [])]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/shapely/geometry/multipolygon.py in __init__(self, polygons, context_type)
     62             self._geom, self._ndim = geos_multipolygon_from_polygons(polygons)
     63         elif context_type == 'geojson':
---> 64             self._geom, self._ndim = geos_multipolygon_from_py(polygons)
     65 
     66     def shape_factory(self, *args):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/shapely/geometry/multipolygon.py in geos_multipolygon_from_py(ob)
    136     assert L >= 1
    137 
--> 138     N = len(ob[0][0][0])
    139     assert N == 2 or N == 3
    140 

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: Side note: `dict` is a builtin type name in Python. Don't define variables with names like `dict`, `list`, `set`, etc., you'll hide the actual type constructors (and cause yourself hard-to-spot problems that are easily avoided)

Comment: Also, include the full error message (and the traceback), with the string you give it's not clear what point of your code raises the error

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I updated my post with the full error message :)

Comment: looks like there's `None` object except `dict`.. the reason could be in your path. Are you sure that relative path 'iris.json' can be found by your script?

Comment: It seems (at least) one of the items in the `iris` dict in `POIsInIris` is the source of the error. The actual error happens in `shapely.geometry.shape`, so check the values in the `iris` dict and make sure they have the correct format